# Parachain block production stalls randomly

Tags: parachain, stalled

Our testnet with 2 collators and 4 validators got stuck producing a single block more than 100 times before finally including it, then production resumed normally as if nothing happened.

Can it be prevented?

How can be parachain nudged from this state when it happens?

This caused [RPC node DB corruption](https://github.com/galacticcouncil/Basilisk-node/issues/411) and downtime for all RPC users. We didn't discover any anomalies in logs or node telemetry. It seems to be related to this cumulus [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/432)

Comment: Polkadot's parachains protocol doesn't handle large blocks very well, but that's not necessarily the cause here. Too non-specific to diagnose, but hopefully will be addressed with the advent of 'Asynchronous Backing': https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/3779

Comment: Did you make very large blocks? If not, you probably need more powerful servers or more stable network between the validators.

Comment: I had a second look at what was actually in all of these blocks and they were pretty much empty and we are running testnet on pretty much the best HW we can get that is outperforming our weight benchmarks.

Comment: Is it build in `--release` mode? Sometimes the dev build can be order of magnitude slower than release mode.

Comment: yes, it is. we also observed this issue on the live network

Comment: There are bugs that are being worked on. I don't think bug reports are suitable for a Q&A website.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug report/complaint, not a question.